# How to filter YouTube URL when entered in a input?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

[image]

How do I filter a YouTube URL like above picture? when Copy paste the URL It  should automatically detect the YouTube and display like above.

can the process done through Laravel or Vue.js ?

Comment: have a look at this page: http://ogp.me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps happen when a user copy/paste any url.

1. In background, client (browser) sends an `AJAX` request to the server with that `URL`.
2. Server then further performs an `HTTP GET` request on that URL
3. Then parses the returned `HTML` and extracts title, description and images.
4. Server bundles this information as `JSON` response and sends it back to the client.
5. Client then display the result to the user

Comment: So we have to design the UI and Fetch the JSON response to it. Is it?

Comment: @ARMkhan Yes. Design the`UI` and then extract meta information from that pasted URL using AJAX

Comment: Oh, Thanks Got it ! :)

Comment: @ARMkhan Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

An idea as to how you can achieve the stated goal perhaps

```
<form name='bert'>
    <textarea name="comment" cols="80" rows="10">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
       Fusce volutpat euismod mauris in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObFligo1hK8 luctus. 
       Sed tempus velit et ipsum vehicula gravida sed in urna.
</textarea>
</form>

<script>
    var pttn=/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/gi;
    var text=document.querySelector( 'form[ name="bert" ] > textarea[ name="comment" ]' );

        text.onchange=function(e){
            var col=this.value.match(pttn);
            if( col.length > 0 ){

                /* an url or some urls of some sort was/were found in the given text */
                col.forEach(function(url,i,a){
                    console.info(url);

                    /* try to fetch the url */
                    fetch( url, { mode:'no-cors', method:'get' } ).then( function(r){
                        /* Process the resonse: this is where the next piece of work is.... using `canvas` perhaps?  */
                        console.log(r)

                    }).catch( function( err ){
                        alert( err )
                    });
                });
            }
        }.bind( text );
</script>
```